# How to list the respective column names when plotting feature importances?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Right now I have this, listing feature importances as numbers, how can i put the column names in the x axis?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=2700, n_features=60, 
n_informative=5, n_redundant=5, random_state=1)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
importance = model.coef_[0]
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

The Output:

```
Feature: 0, Score: -0.11124
Feature: 1, Score: -0.04292
Feature: 2, Score: 0.00561
```

[image]

Comment: using sklearn? Information is missing from the question. Feature names not evident from the question, so where do you find them?

Comment: Yes using sklearn logreg model. I'll update the post and include the code.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example code.

Comment: `plot feature importance` looks like it should throw an Exception - if it does please fix. Please read and provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib Xticks Values in Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838680/matplotlib-xticks-values-in-bar-chart)